# Hibernate and JPA: Could not get a field value by reflection getter

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I'm working with Hibernate and JPA (I upgraded to the latest Hibernate version 4.2.2) and I'm getting a bizarre error.  "Could not get a field value by reflection getter of..."

I'm using JPA, Hibernate, with inheritance.

My code.

AbstractGraphPropertyContainer.java

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="containertype", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name="graphcontainers")
public abstract class AbstractGraphPropertyContainer implements DataObject  {


public AbstractGraphPropertyContainer(){    

}   

public AbstractGraphPropertyContainer(long id){ 
    this.id = id;
}

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="containerid")
long id;

@Column(name = "searchable")
public boolean searchable = true;

@Transient
Map<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<String, String>();

@Transient
private boolean retrieved = false;

static PortalFactory factory = SQLGraphManager.factory;

public long getID(){
    Hibernate.initialize(this);
    return this.id;
}


public void delete(){

    Session session = null;

    try {

        SessionFactory sFactory = SQLGraphManager.fac;
        session = sFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

        //Save this object
        session.delete(this);

        tr.commit();

    }catch(HibernateException he){
        throw new RuntimeException(he);
    }

}

public void save(){

    if(this.id > 0){
        this.update();
        return;
    }

    Session session = null;

    try {


        SessionFactory sFactory = SQLGraphManager.fac;
        session = sFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

        //Save this object
        session.save(this);

        tr.commit();


    }catch(HibernateException he){


        throw new RuntimeException(he);
    }

}

public void update(){


    Session session = null;

    try {
        SessionFactory sFactory = SQLGraphManager.fac;
        session = sFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();

        //Save this object
        session.update(this);

        tr.commit();



    }catch(HibernateException he){

        throw new RuntimeException(he);           
    }       

}
}
```

SQLGraph.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="graphs")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="graphid")
@DiscriminatorValue("GRAPH")
public class SQLGraph extends AbstractGraphPropertyContainer implements Graph {


@Column(name="graph_name")
String name;

@Column(name="graph_description")
String description;

@Column(name="schemalocked")
boolean schemaLocked;

@Column(name="detached")
boolean detached;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="graphs_schemas", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="graphid")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="schemaid")})
private Set<SQLGraphSchema> schemas = new TreeSet<SQLGraphSchema>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="graphs_objects", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="graphid")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="objectid")})  
private Set<SQLGraphObject> objects = new TreeSet<SQLGraphObject>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="graphs_relationships", 
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="graphid")}, 
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="relationshipid")})    
private Set<SQLGraphRelationship> relationships = new TreeSet<SQLGraphRelationship>();


}
```

SQLGraphAction.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="zeusportalgraphactions_typemap") 
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="actionid")
@DiscriminatorValue("ACTION")
public class SQLGraphAction extends SQLGraphRelation<Member, GraphObject> implements
    GraphAction {



@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="endobjectid") 
SQLGraphObject endObject;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="typeid")
SQLGraphActionType type;
```

}

SQLGraphObject.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="graphobjects") 
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="objectid")
@DiscriminatorValue("OBJECT")
public class SQLGraphObject extends AbstractGraphPropertyContainer implements
    GraphObject {


@Column(name="label")
String label;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="typeid")
SQLGraphObjectType type;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="startObject")
private Set<SQLGraphRelationship> relationships = new TreeSet<SQLGraphRelationship>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="endObject")
private Set<SQLGraphRelationship> incRelationships =  new TreeSet<SQLGraphRelationship>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="endObject")
private Set<SQLGraphAction> actions = new TreeSet<SQLGraphAction>();
```

}

The error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.enetexperience.zeusportal.sql.graph.SQLGraphObject.actions
                                                        at com.enetexperience.zeusportal.sql.graph.AbstractGraphPropertyContainer.save(AbstractGraphPropertyContainer.java:269)
                                                        at com.enetexperience.zeusportal.sql.graph.SQLGraphManager.createObject(SQLGraphManager.java:306)
                                                        at com.enetexperience.zeusportal.graph.GraphManagerProxy.createObject(GraphManagerProxy.java:191)
                                                        at com.enetexperience.zeusportal.graph.GraphManagerProxy.getObject(GraphManagerProxy.java:330)
                                                        at com.enetexperience.zeusportal.graph.GraphSearchManager.addToIndex(GraphSearchManager.java:181)
                                                        at com.enetexperience.zeusportal.graph.GraphSearchManager.updateIndex(GraphSearchManager.java:455)
                                                        ... 3 more
                                                      Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.enetexperience.zeusportal.sql.graph.SQLGraphObject.actions
                                                        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:62)
                                                        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:630)
                                                        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValue(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4522)
                                                        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:166)
                                                        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:424)
                                                        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:263)
                                                        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
                                                        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
                                                        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
                                                        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
                                                        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
                                                        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
                                                        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
                                                        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
                                                        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
                                                        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
                                                        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                                        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                                                        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
                                                        at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
                                                        at sun.proxy.$Proxy80.save(Unknown Source)
                                                        at com.enetexperience.zeusportal.sql.graph.AbstractGraphPropertyContainer.save(AbstractGraphPropertyContainer.java:261)
                                                        ... 8 more
                                                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Set field com.enetexperience.zeusportal.sql.graph.SQLGraphObject.actions to com.enetexperience.zeusportal.sql.graph.SQLGraphObject
                                                        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
                                                        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
                                                        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
                                                        at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:376)
                                                        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:59)
                                                        ... 30 more
```

I've looked over StackOverFlow and other sources as to the cause of this error.  But no luck.  The error occurs when saving SQLGraphObject.  Apparently it thinks I'm trying to assign a SQLGraphObject object to a Set property when saving.

Interestingly enough, SQLGraph which extends from the same super class, saves with no issue.

I'm assuming there is something about SQLGraphObject that is causing it to error out, but I can not see what is different between it and SQLGraph.

Update:  When removing the set mappings in SQLGraphObject I get the same error with string an primitive fields.  When removing all the field mappings, I then get the same error regarding the id and searchable fields in the superclass AbstractGraphPropertyContainer.java.  Saving SQLGraph does not give me any issues.

Comment: Can you post the source of `SQLGraphAction`?

Comment: I updated the source with SQLGraphAction but I don't think that's the problem.  When debugging, I removed most of the mappings in SQLGraphObject, however even saving primitives and string values caused the same error.